Different styles of comments in emacs mode
I'm working on the integrating Proof General(PG) into a proof assistant, but I have difficulty in configuration of comments. I have different settings for single-line comments and multi-line comments as above:
{` this is a comment block, 
it allows multiple lines `}

` this is a comment line, it must be just one line

Also, they can appear inside commands like
def NAME := ...
   ` explanatory comments for the definitions
   ARGUMENTS

In PG, there are variables like proof-script-comment-start-regexp and proof-script-comment-end-regexp, but multiple syntax does not working for them. Instead of these variables, we can also use comment-start and comment-end, I mean usual emacs variables. For comment highlighting, I used modify-syntax-table with the setup above
'(?\` "< 23b")
'(?\n "> b")
'(?\{ "(}1nb")
'(?\} "){4nb")

My problem is that I cannot have both styles in compilation. If I only have block comments, that's fine. But I would like to add single-line comment syntax too. Highlighting is working as I expected, but it is not working in proof scripting in PG. Is there any way to achieve it?

https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

@Drew thanks for the correction
